# CSS Animation Dynamic Starting State

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have two animations, one triggered on hover and the other triggered on exiting hover.  I'd like to learn:

how to start the exit-hover animation where the hover animation stops, regardless of how far along it has progressed.

OR

even if exiting hover early, the animation continues to the end, then immediately does the exit-hover animation.

Currently if you exit hover too quickly, it jumps to the starting position of the exit-hover animation.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kevmon/dwsp6v91/)

HTML

```
<div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-container {
  margin: 50px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
img.over {
  -webkit-animation: enlarge .5s cubic-bezier(.42,0,.8,1) both,
         enlarge-2 .25s cubic-bezier(.2,0,.3,1) .5s forwards;
}
img.out {
  -webkit-animation-name: shrink;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-direction: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes enlarge {
  from {transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);}
  to {transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.5);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes enlarge-2 {
  from {transform: scale(1.5);}
  to {transform: scale(1.3);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3);}
  to {transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);}
}
```

JavaScript

```
$("img").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is untested, but shows the idea of using a semaphore and at the start of the animation schedule a timeout to release the semaphore at the end of the animation.

```
function hoverAnimationHandler(context, intervalLength) {
    var alreadyRunning = false;
    var currentEvent = undefined;
    var scheduledAction = undefined;
    function runEvent(currentContext, event) {
        if (alreadyRunning) {
            if (currentEvent !== event) {
                scheduledAction = event;
            }
        } else {
            alreadyRunning = true;
            currentEvent = event;
            event(currentContext);
            setTimeout(function() {
                currentEvent = undefined;
                alreadyRunning = false;
            }, intervalLength);
        }
    }
    function hover(currentContext) {
        currentContext.removeClass("out").addClass("hover");
    }
    function unHover(currentContext) {
        currentContext.removeClass("hover").addClass("out");
    }
    context.hover(function() {
        runEvent($(this), hover);
    }, function() {
        runEvent($(this), unHover);
    });
}
```